# iphone - tableView viewForHeaderInSection is called N times... is this normal?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableViewController based class. I noticed that the

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

method is called N times, where N is the number of rows the table has.

It this normal?

Wasn't the header for a section being supposed just to be drawn once for that secion?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewForHeaderInSection` will be called depending on how many sections you have for your table. Try to post some more of your code, maybe from `cellForIndexPathAtRow` cause there's no way of really telling why you are experiencing this issue from what you have provided.